# How to generate a json using jsonbuilder in groovy with key : pair value within a key

Tags: json, groovy

I need to generate a json using json builder which i am doing like this

```
class DynamicJson{
  def effective_date
}
json = new DynamicJson(effective_date:["year":'2012',"month":'8',"day":'2',
"hour":'22',"minute":'12',"second":'12',"millis":'0',"time_zone":'UTC'])
```

which is producing

```
{"effective_date":{"year": 2012,"month":8,"day":2,"hour":22,"minute":12,"second":12,
  "millis":0,"time_zone":"UTC"}}
```

**But the output i want is :**

```
{"effective_date":{"year": 2012,"month": 8,"day": 2,"hour": 22,
"minute": 19, "second": 12,"millis": 0,"time_zone":{"id": "UTC"}}
```

How can i generate

```
"time_zone":{"id": "UTC"}?
```

Comment: Call the constructor with `time_zone:[id:'UTC']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your constructor to:

```
json = new DynamicJson(effective_date:[
    year:'2012',
    month:'8',
    day:'2',
    hour:'22',
    minute:'12',
    second:'12',
    millis:'0',
    time_zone:[id:'UTC']
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
json = new DynamicJson(effective_date:["year":'2012',"month":'8',"day":'2',
"hour":'22',"minute":'12',"second":'12',"millis":'0',"time_zone":["id":'UTC']])